# Scrape links with casperjs/phantomjs

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, css-selectors, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to scrape all "Box Score" links on http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/GSW/2016_games.html. It would be perfect if someone showed me a way to click on them one by one, but just scrape them would already be amazing.
Using 'a'-selector I managed to scrape all links from page:

```
$('tbody tr a').each(function (i) {
            console.log([i + 1, $(this).text(), ' // ' + $(this).attr('href')].join(': '));
        });
```

But I don't see a way how to specify Box-score links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selector will do what you want:

```
#teams_games > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5) > a
```

A helpeful tip-- if you use developer tools in Chrome, you can right click an inspected element and choose Copy >> Copy Selector to get a css selector for it. That is usually a good starting point for making a more generalizable selector for cases like this.

Comment: The feeling that I got this right was delusive. I want to make an array of links. This is my code:                         scrape_links = function() {
    var array = [];
    $('#teams_games tbody tr td:nth-child(5) a').each(function () {
        array.push($(this).attr('href'));
    });
    return array;  
}           And I invoke this function inside page.evaluate-function like this:   page.evaluate( function() {
        links = scrape_links();
    });                I get an error: Can't find variable: scrape_links